How can I locate this chemical test strip in the picture? OpenCV canny edge detection does not draw the bounding box
I have an image that i would like to do an edge detection and draw a bounding box to it, my problem is my python code does not draw the bounding box and im not sure if its because it was not able to detect any objects in it or im just drawing the rectangle wrong.

Here is my attempt
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
(B, G, R) = cv2.split(img)
img = cv2.Canny(B, 20, 100)   # Blue channel gives the best box so far
# img = cv2.Canny(R, 20, 100)
# img = cv2.Canny(R, 20, 100)


ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,20,100,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)


cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)

for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.intp(box)
    img = cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)



# display the image with bounding rectangle drawn on it 
# cv2.namedWindow('Bounding Rectangle', cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
cv2.imshow('Bounding Rectangle', img) 

cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

This produces this image

and I am expecting an image that is something like this:


Do not overwrite your input with your canny edge.  The input is 3 channel and canny edge image is one channel. So when you try to write a red box on img, it won't work because you need to make img 3 channel again to write color.  Also your contours are not going to be about all the boxes. They are going to be about each line segment.  minAreaRect is not going to combine all the lines into one outline. It will be draw for each contour which is about each line segment.  You could try getting the convex hull of all the white points in the threshold image. Then get minAreaRect.

Canny detects salient edges. You want to detect a region. These are two different tasks! Canny is just not suited for your task.

Please check out my another answer for an approach which solves some of the issues you have faced on the way of trying to arrive at an image manipulation steps which allow to detect all of the four fields - it is in this use case not necessary ... thinking out of the box allows sometimes to arrive at better solutions than focusing on the image object detection.

My approach:

optional: correct white balance so that the background loses its tint
convert to color space with saturation channel, threshold that
contours, minAreaRect

This approach detects all four colored squares.
# you can skip this step by defining `balanced = im * np.float32(1/255)`

# gray = im.mean(axis=(0,1), dtype=np.float32) # gray world
gray = np.median(im, axis=(0,1)).astype(np.float32) # majority vote
print(gray) # [137. 127. 140.]
balanced = (im / gray) * 0.8 # some moderate scaling so it's not "overexposed"


# transform into color space that has a "saturation" axis
hsv = cv.cvtColor(balanced, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
H,S,V = cv.split(hsv)
# squares nicely visible in S


for comparison, the saturation channel of the source, without white balance:

# Otsu finds threshold level automatically
(_, mask) = cv.threshold((S * 255).astype(np.uint8), 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# To remove minor debris/noise. Increase iterations as needed.
mask = cv.morphologyEx(mask, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel=None, iterations=5)


(contours, _) = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hull = cv.convexHull(np.concatenate(contours))
rrect = cv.minAreaRect(hull)

# visualization
canvas = im.copy()
cv.drawContours(image=canvas, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(255,255,0), thickness=7)
# cv.drawContours(image=canvas, contours=[hull], contourIdx=-1, color=(255,255,0), thickness=7)
rrect_points = cv.boxPoints(rrect).round().astype(int)
cv.polylines(canvas, [rrect_points], isClosed=True, color=(0,255,255), thickness=3)



The code in one piece, minus some imshow/imwrite:
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread("picture.jpg")

# gray = im.mean(axis=(0,1), dtype=np.float32) # gray world
gray = np.median(im, axis=(0,1)).astype(np.float32) # majority vote
print(gray) # [137. 127. 140.]
balanced = (im / gray) * 0.8 # some moderate scaling so it's not "overexposed"

# transform into color space that has a "saturation" axis
hsv = cv.cvtColor(balanced, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
H,S,V = cv.split(hsv)
# squares nicely visible in S

# Otsu finds threshold level automatically
(_, mask) = cv.threshold((S * 255).astype(np.uint8), 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# To remove minor debris/noise. Increase iterations as needed.
mask = cv.morphologyEx(mask, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel=None, iterations=5)

(contours, _) = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hull = cv.convexHull(np.concatenate(contours))
rrect = cv.minAreaRect(hull)

# visualization
canvas = im.copy()
cv.drawContours(image=canvas, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(255,255,0), thickness=7)
# cv.drawContours(image=canvas, contours=[hull], contourIdx=-1, color=(255,255,0), thickness=7)
rrect_points = cv.boxPoints(rrect).round().astype(int)
cv.polylines(canvas, [rrect_points], isClosed=True, color=(0,255,255), thickness=3)


What? No Canny? ;)

Thank you so much , i actually dont mind that its not using Canny since it captured the orange color also (which i was planning to fix later anyway)

I also like that you are using rectangle coordinates, since i can use it to crop the images :)

If you need an image sampled out of a rotated rectangle, several ways: (1) warpAffine using M calculated from the rotated rect values (2) boxPoints, get homography or lesser transform from that, warp. (1) Is my personal preference. Rotation may be ambiguous, four orientations possible. Can be normalized so you get it in landscape orientation and also not upside down

If you need decent quantitative color measurements out of this, I'd also recommend minding the gamma compression. I didn't bother with that for just the localization. And of course fixed lighting and camera settings

Question , how do you prevent stray readings?. For example this image has some stray readings that messes up with the yellow bounding box, result. I could just crop this portion out, but is there anyway to make the script more resiliant to these? I tried playing with the balance value but it did not really help much.

I actually was able to make the crop and rotate to landscape on my own (pretty proud of this one). Using warpAffine and doing some geometry with the rrect_points

are you able to extract the area value of the skyblue bounding box? so i could filter our bounding boxes that have smaller / larger than expected area

the picture you linked to shows some dye stains on the left edge. those can be removed with morphology operations on the binary mask mask = cv.morphologyEx(mask.astype(np.uint8), cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel=None, iterations=5).astype(bool) -- yes, each square's contents can be sampled. the contours are right there. -- sure you can filter those contours by area. cv.contourArea helps with that. -- I think that's enough encore for now. Please ask a new question for anything that goes beyond the original question.

The mask and contour area filtering did the trick, i was able to process all my images with no problem now, thank you so much sir

@THESIS : much more interesting here is the question : were you able to arrive at the right readings of color and its intensity of this urine-test-strips from the images?

@Christoph Rackwitz It is nice to have code segmented with images to show step-by-step results. But I think that it would be further helpful (and more easily testable) to others (esp. beginners) to include the full code all put together.

@Christoph Rackwitz. Thanks for adding the full code. Much more helpful in my opinion.

the image quality is not very good. GaussianBlur was used to make the edges more distinct and to remove noise
 import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5,5), 0)

_, img_thresh = cv2.threshold(img_blur, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) # cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU can use

cv2.imshow("thresh", img_thresh)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)

for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.intp(box)
    img = cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)

# # display the image with bounding rectangle drawn on it 
cv2.imshow('Bounding Rectangle', img) 

cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

img_thresh:

result:


you were the first to suggest a threshold on gray, and to suggest Otsu, and you got decent results with that. -- the only things left are to deal with debris and get a box around all detections.

Here are 2 alternate methods for Python/OpenCV that do not require finding a threshold or adjusting the brightness contrast, nor get contours and combine them.
Unfortunately, my OpenCV is broken at the moment. So I cannot test. If someone would check them out and correct anything that would be terrific.
The downside is that they both are likely to be slower than finding contours.
The both methods convert to LAB and selects the B channel and does otsu threshold.  The first method finds the convex hull from the threshold points and then the rotated rectangle.  The second method, skips the convex hull and gets the rotated rectangle directly from the threshold points.
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    
    # read the image
    img = cv2.imread('chemtest.jpg')
    
    # convert to LAB and select the B channel
    B = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)[:,:,2]
    
    # Otsu threshold
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    
    # Optional morphology to clean up small spots if needed. Not include here
 
    # Get points from threshold image or after morphology
    points = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh.transpose() > 0))
   
    # Get convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(points)
    
    # Get rotated rectangle
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(hull)
    box = np.intp(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
    
    # draw rotated rect
    result1 = img.copy()
    cv2.polylines(result1, [box], True, (0,0,255), 2)
    
    # save result1
    cv2.imwrite('chemtest_box1.jpg', result1)
    
    # show outline image
    cv2.imshow('result1', result1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    
    
    --------------------------------------
    
    # Alternate Skip Convex Hull:
    
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    
    # read the image
    img = cv2.imread('chemtest.jpg')
    
    # convert to LAB and select the B channel
    B = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)[:,:,2]
    
    # Otsu threshold
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    
    # Optional morphology to clean up small spots if needed. Not include here

    # Get points from threshold (or after morphology)
    points = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh.transpose() > 0))

    # Get rotated rect directly from the threshold points
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(points)    
    box = np.intp(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
    
    # draw rotated rect
    result2 = img.copy()
    cv2.polylines(result2, [box], True, (0,0,255), 2)
    
    # save result2
    cv2.imwrite('chemtest_box2.jpg', result2)
    
    # show result2
    cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)





Why do you say you have to scan the image twice?  I don't see that in my script. The image is in memory already. The otsu algorithm may process the image once to get the threshold and a second time to apply it. But there is no second reading from disk.

It is not in your script ... it is hidden in the OTSU ... which needs first to build a histogram going through the data of the entire image to decide about the threshold and then run over this data again to provide the thresholded result. With a constant manually chosen threshold you skip one loop over the image data which can at large images be saving much computation time.

Correct.  However, how long does it take you to tune a good manual threshold and does the same value work for all your chemical strip images?

In case I had to actually do it in a laboratory I would anyway prefer interactive use, so I can see if the result is OK not relying on the object finding risking delivery of wrong results to the customers without prior checking their plausibility. And interactive I would be able to adjust the threshold value if necessary.

I do not see it.  Send it again. What is it about?

Sorry, I don't understand why you sent that to me. Are you asking me to contribute software somewhere?

I only do scripting.  Don't have much experience with C or C++.

oOo is about programming using English as programming language ... following this approach you don't need to learn a programming language in order to write programs - only be skilled in precise formulation of sentences using spoken language (English or any other). It would be sure interesting to turn imagemagick cryptic sequences of options and commands into easy to understand English sentences expressing what the code do. If you get the core idea of oOo you could help to make it happen ...

In other words ... what I would like arrive at one day is to turn your excellent imagemagick shell scripts into easy readable and understandable sequence of English sentences describing what the code does and at the same time being able to be run as script doing what it tells it do. This way the documentation will be the actual code. Isn't this worth the effort to make it happen?

I do not understand. My web site has a list of scripts and a description of each all on one page.

Yes ... but the code is separate from the description what it does. These are two parts: a part with explanation and a part with code. The idea is to create a system of scripts representing some functionalities giving them such names that it becomes possible to write a sentence with words being commands without disturbing the text flow. So it will read like explanation and can be run too. No need for separate explanation and code block anymore and all is understandable and can be easily customized. And yes ... the core idea of oOo is not easy to grasp.

Let's give a simplest example: if you want to know the current working directory you use pwd or echo $PWD. If you have forgotten what the shortcut of it is, you need to search the Internet or help. If you create an executable named: "workingDirectory" you can then use the command line for completions of work and you get displayed all what is available and you see: "workingDirectory" so you use this ... no need to remember the shortcut pwd or any other cryptic one - you don't need to learn anything.

You adapt the system to how you think and speak ... and the system will understand it. But to make it happen you need to know how you think and adapt the system. Then you can use it like you use ChatGPT or other AI.

I have on my system a command in the executable path called "howAreYouBash". If I type at the prompt: howAreYouBash ? I get:  Thanks ... I’m fine.   May the power of oOo be with you oOosys!     How can I help you today? which results in fully another perception of the system which becomes "alive" this way able to respond like a chat partner staying still "stupid" ... but you get the impression it understands ... This is how AI works today - nothing fancy or complicated ... just a huge amount of pre-prepared responses.
